# Python mysql.connector .fetchall() returns (redundant) data in different formats

Tags: mysql-connector-python

I have this method to execute Queries:

```
def exeQuery(query, data, dbEdit ):
try:
    myDatabase = mysql.connector.connect(**dbLoginInfo)
    cursor = myDatabase.cursor()
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print('[ERROR WHILE CONNECTING TO DATABASE]: ', e)
else:
    if dbEdit == True:
        if data == None:
            res = cursor.execute(query)
            myDatabase.commit()
        else:
            res = cursor.execute(query, data)
            myDatabase.commit()
    else:
        if data == None:
            cursor.execute(query)
            res = cursor.fetchall()
            
        else: 
            cursor.execute(query, data)
            res = cursor.fetchall()
            

cursor.close()
myDatabase.close()
#print(type(res))
#print(res)
return  res
```

And I call it here:

```
@app.route("/profil/delete", methods= ['POST'])
@token_required
def deleteProfil():
    dicUser = decodeToken(request.args.get('token'))
    profilName = request.args.get('profilName')

    path = exeQuery('SELECT profilbild FROM Profil WHERE profilName = %s AND konto_email = %s', (profilName, dicUser['user']), False)
    print(path)
    return Response(status = 200)
```

It should print me `('pics/jj@gmail.de/DelProf.png',)` once.
For some reason I get the right data but sometimes the formatting is changing. Everytime there was only one row in the database that fit to the query. These are the three outputs I got so far:

```
[('pics/jj@gmail.de/DelProf.png',), ('pics/jj@gmail.de/DelProf.png',), ('pics/jj@gmail.de/DelProf.png',), ('pics/jj@gmail.de/DelProf.png',)]

[('pics/jj@gmail.de/DelProf.png',)]

('pics/jj@gmail.de/DelProf.png',)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `MySQLCursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples. as mentioned here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html.
Even if there are no results it will return a `list`, but empty `[]`.
If you got a list with repeated values, it's possible that your query it may found those matches.